# Is it possible for a class to be both a vertex and an edge in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I would like to have edges between my edges, but the API and the Studio interface don't seem to provide for this possibility. Is it possible in OrientDB to have a class inherit from both V and E?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The Property Graph model is simple but strict. You should have a vertex in the middle that collects the other edges.